Flutter Firebase App Check - "App attestation failed" 403 Permission Denied Error
I'm using Firebase App Check in my Flutter application, specifically with the firebase_vertexai package. When I attempt to make requests to the Vertex AI service, I consistently encounter the following error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "App attestation failed.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Questions:
Is there something I might have missed in the setup for Firebase App Check in Flutter?
Are there specific configurations or troubleshooting steps I should follow to resolve the "App attestation failed" issue?
Could this be related to a misconfiguration in the Firebase console or the app’s API key restrictions?
Any guidance on resolving this would be greatly appreciated!
Steps I've taken:

[x] I enabled Firebase App Check in the Firebase console for the necessary services.
[x] I integrated the firebase_app_check package in my Flutter project.
[x] I followed the official Firebase App Check documentation to configure App Check with both DeviceCheck (for iOS) and SafetyNet/Play Integrity (for Android).
[x] I ensured that App Check is correctly initialized in my main.dart as shown in the documentation:

AndroidProvider get androidProvider =>
      kDebugMode ? AndroidProvider.debug : AndroidProvider.playIntegrity;

AppleProvider get appleProvider =>
      kDebugMode ? AppleProvider.debug : AppleProvider.deviceCheck;

await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
  androidProvider: androidProvider,
  appleProvider: appleProvider,
);


[x] I confirmed that my google-services.json (for Android) and GoogleService-Info.plist (for iOS) are up to date and correctly configured.

Additional Information:

The Firebase services work correctly when App Check is disabled.
I have attempted to reinstall the app to ensure there are no cache issues.
I'm testing this on both physical devices and emulators/simulators, and the issue persists across all devices.


Although I'm not using Flutter, I'm having the same issue with my web app... If you go to the reCAPTCHA settings in your Google Cloud console, does it show an "unprotected" status? And does it ask you to "finish setting up your key: Request scores"?
